# quiero asignarle una salida a un menu hecho con un switch

Tags: c

quiero que la opcion 5 sea salir del menu

este es el codigo

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a,n,i,j=0,k=0;
int A [100];
int B [100];
int C [100];
int opc;
int main() {
    do {
        do {
            printf("Selecciona una opcion: \n\n");
            printf("1.- Agregar elementos: \n");
            printf("2.- Ver arreglo: \n");
            printf("3.- Ver elementos pares: \n");
            printf("4.- Ver elementos impares: \n");
            printf("5.- Salir\n");
            scanf("%d", &opc);
            fflush(stdin);
        }while(opc<=0 || opc>5);


        switch(opc) {
        case 1:

            printf("\nCuantos elementos quieres en el arreglo? ");
            scanf("%d",&n);

        for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
            printf("\nIntroduce [%d]",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&A[i]);
            fflush(stdin);

    }

    break;
    case 2:
        for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
        printf("%d, ",A[i]);
    }

    break;
case 3:
        printf("\nPARES: ");

        for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
            if(A[i]%2==0){

            B[j]=A[i];
            j++;
            }

    }for (i=0; i<j;i++){
        printf("%d\t",B[i]);
    }


    break;
    case 4:printf("\nIMPARES: ");
        for (i=0; i<n;i++) {
            if(A[i]%2!=0){

            C[k]=A[i];
            k++;
            }

    }for (i=0; i<k;i++){
        printf("%d\t",C[i]);
    }


        break;



        case 5:
    return 0;
    break;
    default:
}   






}while(n!=5);





    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La parte que nos interesa del código es esta:

```
do {
  switch(opc) {
    case 5:
      return 0;
      break;
  }
} while(n!=5);
```

El bucle principal lo tienes configurado para que se abandone el mismo si `n==5`... pero la opción elegida del menú la estás guardando en `opc`. Lo correcto sería entonces:

```
}while(opc != 5);
```

Con esto, lo único que tienes que hacer entonces es eliminar el `return 0`.

```
do {
  switch(opc) {
    case 5:
      break;
  }
} while(opc!=5);
```

Con `return 0` lo que consigues es salir del `main` directamente... par tu caso particular el resultado será el mismo pero el camino a seguir es diferente.

Te sugiero dividir el código en funciones para que sea más sencillo de gestionar... y, por favor, evita el uso de variables globales.